# Why does a CanCan defined in a block always return true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm trying to use CanCan to define an ability in a block. In ability.rb I have the permission defined as:

```
can [:create, :show], Comment do |comment|
  if !group.nil?
      is_a_group_member(current_user_group_member) == true
  elsif user.admin?
    is_a_user_admin(current_user)
  end
end
```

No matter what this is always returning true. However, if I write the ability in one line:

```
can [:create, :show], Comment if (!group.nil? && is_a_group_member(current_user_group_member) == true) || (user.admin? && is_a_user_admin(current_user))
```

When the ability.rb permission uses one line it works as expected. When I use a block it always returns true. Any ideas or thoughts on why this is breaking? Thanks

Comment: It's explictly explained in the gem's doc that you should use blocks only for conditions on the resource itself

Comment: `The block is only evaluated when an actual instance object is present. It is not evaluated when checking permissions on the class (such as in the index action). This means any conditions which are not dependent on the object attributes should be moved outside of the block.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` ... `else` part is an expression and evaluates to either `nil`, if the condition is false, or, if the condition is true, to whatever the conditional code evaluates to.

In your case, in the multiline `if`, if `!group.nil?` is true, `is_a_group_member(current_user_group_member) == true` is returned. If `user.admin?` is true, `is_a_user_admin(current_user)` is returned. So if either of them is true, `true` will be returned.